# java heap space error while trying git push

Tags: java, git

I have been trying to push my commit to the git repository but it is showing "**java heap space error**". The log of the push is shown below:

```
Counting objects: 108, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (93/93), done.
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
Writing objects: 100% (108/108), 561.41 MiB | 4.91 MiB/s, done.
Total 108 (delta 51), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unpack failed: error Java heap space
To https://repo_address
! [remote rejected] dev -> dev (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://repo_address'
```

I did some research online but there are some solutions existing for gerrit which I am not using.

Comment: How is the target repo hosted? Are you doing this on the command line or through an IDE? Looks like you're pushing half a gigabyte of data to the remote and either it can't take that much data, or your client can't (hence why the IDE question). Why is there so much in the push? Large binaries?

Comment: @MarkFisher I am trying through command line. I have a installer module that has some resources included for the installer. But funny thing is I removed the resources by adding that folder to .gitignore file. Still it is writing almost the same amount of data. And apart from the Installer module I have not changed anything in other modules that can have any effect.

Comment: If you added the files to your commit, then .gitignore is not enough, you also need to remove them from the commit object using `git rm --cached <path/to/file>` and then do `git commit --amend`. using the `--cached` option ensures they aren't physically delete from your filesystem, just from the repo

Comment: @MarkFisher since I am new at git, I got stuck at the 'git commit --ammend' command. it went to an editor and I do not know what to do here! I tried to do normal commit thing, but that did not solve the problem

Comment: I'll write an answer for your issue rather than in notes. I appreciate it may not be the real answer (which is just - contact the upstream host and ask them why they aren't accepting large pushes)

Comment: @MarkFisher I do appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is in response to your issue of removing large files from your current commit and then re-pushing your commit to see if it is the large installs that are causing the problem.

Imagine starting with this dir structure:

```
.git/
libs/somefile.jar
    /someotherfile.jar
src/otherstuff.java
```

In your current situation, you have a bunch of files in your commit that you are trying to push, but you realise you actually want to remove some extras you've added that are not needed upstream, but you do want to keep locally, but also make it so they never get pushed up.

You can see what files are in your current commit with:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --decorate --numstat HEAD^..HEAD
```

Now, we want to create a new commit object without the libs/ folder, and mark it in .gitignore so it's never added in future.

```
# either do this recursively to the dir with this command:
git rm -r --cached libs

# or individual name the files:
git rm --cached libs/somefile.jar
git rm --cached libs/someotherfile.jar
```

Now you have local changes, you can see them with `git status`:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    libs/somefile.jar
    deleted:    libs/someotherfile.jar

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    libs/
```

If you look at your filesystem, the files should still be there. That's what `--cached` did - kept the workspace files, only removed them from git repo.

Now we edit the .gitignore file and add entries for either `/libs/` or name the files individually, and then add that to your changeset:

```
git add .gitignore
```

Finally we want to commit all these changes, replacing the old commit with all the large files in it.

This is done with `git commit --amend`. All this does is replace your current commit with a new one, rather than adding a new commit on top of the old one.

It will pop up the usual dialog for the commit message. You can keep it the same as it was if you like, or add some additional notes to the commit message. This will be the commit message of the new commit, replacing the old commit entirely (ie. the lib files will be gone from the commit).

If you do a git status, you should see you're still 1 commit ahead of origin/master, and if you check the files in the commit itself (with the `git log ...` command above) it shouldn't have any of your unwanted files in it.

Now try pushing back to the remote.

If you're stuck at some point from an earlier situation, post your `git status` output. It usually gives you all the hints you need to know how to continue.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It was really enlightening. But unfortunately the data amount stays the same. my `git status` output follows: 
 `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 15 commits` maybe the previous commits are causing the data size to stay big still?? as the previous commits included the binaries?

Comment: Yes, I had assumed (and stated in my answer) you were only 1 commit ahead of remote. Generally with git you push to remotes a single commit representing change for the work you are doing if possible. If this is the case, then you can reduce your 15 commits to 1 using interactive rebasing. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History for excellent explanation. If you do squash all your 15 commits to 1, then you can then remove your binaries from it as described above.

Comment: Alternatively, if you need to keep all 15 separate, you can step through each commit and push them individually to remote. I would do this by first branching your current head `git checkout -b keep-me; git checkout master` to keep it safe, then getting all commit ids in your history `git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short -20 HEAD`, and reset your master to each one in turn `git reset --hard aabbccdd` (where aabbccdd is the commit id from the history, the oldest first), and pushing each commit in turn. Rebasing is easier, but is rewriting history, so destructive

Comment: Glad I could help. Mark the answer if you're happy with it please :-)